# Converting .pcap files to .txt using tshark

Tags: networking, permissions, sudo, wireshark, tcpdump

I am trying to convert my .pcap packet capture files generated by tcpdump into a text format.  I am getting a permission error whenever I try to convert the .pcap file or even just port ">" the stdout of tcpdump into a text file.

Method 1:

generate packet capture files using

```
sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 -w /var/log/tcpdump/tcpdump-log-06-03-2015.pcap
```

attempt to convert the .pcap file using

```
sudo tshark -V -r tcpdump-log-06-03-2015.pcap > tcpdump-log-06-03-2015.txt
```

But I get a permission denied error like this:

```
bash: tcpdump-log-06-03-2015.txt: Permission denied
```

Method 2:

generate packet capture files using

```
sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 > /var/log/tcpdump/tcpdump-log-06-03-2015.txt
```

I get a similar permission denied error:

```
bash: /var/log/tcpdump/tcpdump-log-06-03-2015.txt: Permission denied
```

Since I am running both commands as sudo, I figured that permissions would be a non-issue.

I have disabled apparmor for tcpdump by running this command:

```
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.tcpdump
```

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening?  Or suggest a better way to generate readable text output for tcpdump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the redirection portion of your commands are executed as you and not root.
So, if you want to keep your destination directory as it is, then you need to get that part to run as root also. Alternatively, you could make your destination directory one that you have write access for.
Example showing why it is not working (notice the permissions on the resulting file):

```
$ sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -r eth1-2015-04-16-17-01-35.bin > vvvbbb.txt
reading from file eth1-2015-04-16-17-01-35.bin, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
$ ls -l vvvbbb.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 doug doug 5418673 Jun  2 16:53 vvvbbb.txt
```

Example of a method that will work (Again, notice the permissions on the resulting file):

```
$ sudo su
# tcpdump -n -tttt -r eth1-2015-04-16-17-01-35.bin >vvvbbb.txt
reading from file eth1-2015-04-16-17-01-35.bin, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
# ls -l vvvbbb.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5418673 Jun  2 16:57 vvvbbb.txt
# exit
exit
$
```

Example of another method that will work, but spews also to the terminal, which may be undesirable:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -r eth1-2015-04-16-17-01-35.bin | sudo tee vvvbbb.txt
... delete tons of spew to terminal ...
$ ls -l vvv*.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5418673 Jun  2 17:01 vvvbbb.txt
```

Note: I have used tcpdump here instead of tshark, but only because I don't have tshark installed.

Comment: Wow, that's  perfect!  Didn't know about sudo's scope not including what comes after a "|"... Good to know!  I got the tcpdump output in the readable text file now.  Much thanks!